# Extract lines between two patterns with awk and a variable regex

Tags: regex, awk, multiline

I'm searching for a way to extract the lines between two patterns with awk with the use
of variables. Each section ends where the next one starts.

Example file:

```
[ SECTION_1 ]
info 1
info 2
info 3
[ SECTION_2 ]
info 4
info 5
info 6
[ SOMETHING_SOMETHING_DARK_SIDE ]
...
[ WE_have_COokIES ]
```

with

```
awk '/^\[ SECTION_1 \]/{p=1;next} /^\[ [!-~]+ \]/{p=0} p' "${MY_FILE_PATH}"
```

I get what I want:

```
info 1
info 2
info 3
```

But I would like to have something like this:

```
function get { 
  awk '/^\[ "$1" \]/{p=1;next} /^\[ [!-~]+ \]/{p=0} p' "${MY_FILE_PATH}"
}
```

Nothing seems to work :( Any ideas or hints?

Comment: How do you get what you want, that awk won't print anything ?

Comment: Oh thanks, there was a typo in it. It should be `.../{p=0} p`. I corrected it in my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quoting it wrong with double quotes. Positional parameter `$1` is not expanded in since it's still enclosed in single quotes. It should be:

```
function get { 
    awk '/^\[ '"$1"' \]/{p=1;next} /^\[ [!-~]+ \]/{p=0} f' "${MY_FILE_PATH}"
}
```

Perhaps another good way is to use `-v`. At least critical syntax errors may be avoided:

```
function get { 
    awk -v s="$1" '$0 ~ "^\\[ " s " \\]"{p=1;next} /^\[ [!-~]+ \]/{p=0} f' "${MY_FILE_PATH}"
}
```

Comment: Never use that first approach as it is full of caveats and potential bugs. The second one is close but you need to double-escape RE meta-characters withing string literals - as written `\[` is the same as `[`, you need `\\[`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes you're correct. I missed quoting that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler/clearer as:

```
awk -v sect="$1" '/^\[ [!-~]+ \]/{ f = ($0 ~ "^\\[ " sect " \\]") } f' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you have an entirely different approach using sed;
It first uses a regular expression the get rid of the lines starting with [
and than it removes the empty lines.

```
$ sed 's/^\[.*//g' sections.txt | sed '/^$/d'
info 1
info 2
info 3
info 4
info 5
info 6
```

Comment: ..., but that does not meet the requirements to get the content of the specified section itself.