# Print the smallest set of lines between two patterns (BEGIN and END) including the lines of these two patterns

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk, sed

### Input file

```
aaa
Any--END--Pattern
bbb
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN
ccc                   # do not print
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN   # print 1
ddd                   # print 2
Any--END--Pattern     # print 3
eee
fff
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN   # print 4
ggg                   # print 5
Any--END--Pattern     # print 6
hhh                   # print 7
Any--END--Pattern     # print 8
iii                   # do not print
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN
jjj
```

### Wanted output

```
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN   # print 1
ddd                   # print 2
Any--END--Pattern     # print 3
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN   # print 4
ggg                   # print 5
Any--END--Pattern     # print 6
hhh                   # print 7
Any--END--Pattern     # print 8
```

### Notes

- Print from the latest `ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN` before the current `Any--END--Pattern`.
- Print until the last `Any--END--Pattern` if no `ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN` meet.

### Many similar questions but cannot find an answer for this issue

- [One-liner to print all lines between two patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933989) [perl]
- [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736) [awk/sed/grep]
- [awk print only lines between two patterns removing first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895208)
- [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756)
- [Extract lines between two patterns with awk and a variable regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779667)
- [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756)
- ...

The answers I have tested from these questions print the line `ccc` and/or the line `iii`... or do not print the lines having the `BEGIN` and `END` patterns. My several attempts have these same drawbacks and defects.

We could write a ten lines script, but I am sure there is an elegant one-line command solving this issue but I cannot find it. Therefore I think this could be a good SO question ;-)

I wonder what are the tricks to use from `sed`, `awk`, `perl` or any other tool available easy on our Unix-like systems. Please provide a tiny command line using : [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) or any other tool you think...

---

## EDIT:

Just to underline the pretty simple command line from [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep)'s comment that simplifies the problem by reversing the input file:

```
tac input.txt | sed -n '/END/,/BEGIN/p' | tac
```

But this command line also prints the beginning
<sup>(this case may not happen for other users looking a similar issue)</sup>

```
aaa
Any--END--Pattern
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN   # print 1
ddd                   # print 2
Any--END--Pattern     # print 3
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN   # print 4
ggg                   # print 5
Any--END--Pattern     # print 6
hhh                   # print 7
Any--END--Pattern     # print 8
```

<sub>(This answer is used within [this C++ coding rules](https://github.com/olibre/CppCoding/blob/gh-pages/cpp/rules.md#fiqc--double-quotes--and-angle-brackets-))</sub>

Comment: OK, you've read all those answers...have you made an attempt of your own, based on what you've read? If so, what problems are you facing?

Comment: You phrased this question like a code golf request. Judging from your experience, you should know better. ;)

Comment: What do you want then, if you already have those answers?

Comment: @simbabque I can write a script to handle this, but I think this is possible using a one-line command but I cannot find :-/ I think this could be a good question for SO, don't you ?

Comment: @123 I have posted too quicly my question. There are many similar questions I have read, but I cannot find an answer for my issue :-/

Comment: @olibre I can't work out how the other questions don't answer this?

Comment: @123 Most of the other answers and my own attempts print the line `ccc`. I am checking your last command of your answer ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui: The output is not exactly the same. It doesn't contain the borderlines, and it prints `ccc`, too.

Comment: @choroba yep, I noticed later. The problem here is that the OP wants to print when the PAT2 occurs for the last time in a given block, so it keeps adding stuff in the buffer. Weird case. I got close adapting [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/1983854) with `awk 'flag{ if (/Any--END--Pattern/){buf=buf $0 ORS; printf "%s", buf; flag=0; buf=""} else buf = buf $0 ORS}; /ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN/{flag=1; buf=$0 ORS}' file`

Comment: @TomFenech Thank you for your feedback about my original question, I have explained better my issue and why the other similar questions do not apply. (I will delete this comment and other of my comments later.) Cheers

Comment: becomes simpler by reversing input file, `tac ip.txt | sed -n '/Any--END--Pattern/,/ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN/p' | tac` but with unnecessary first two lines of input file...

Comment: @Sundeep Lovely tiny and understandable answer ;-) And I do not care about the little drawback about the extra `Any--END--Pattern`. Congratulations :-)

Comment: Hi @Sundeep  I am using your trick in my document: https://github.com/olibre/CppCoding/blob/gh-pages/cpp/rules.md#fiqc--double-quotes--and-angle-brackets-  I am requesting to reopen this question in order to let you provide your pretty simple answer. Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/BEGIN/{c=0; b=1} 
              {a[c++]=$0} 
      b&&/END/{for(i=0;i<c;i++) print a[i]; delete a; c=0}' file

ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN   # print 1
ddd                   # print 2
Any--END--Pattern     # print 3
ANY--BEGIN--PATTERN   # print 4
ggg                   # print 5
Any--END--Pattern     # print 6
hhh                   # print 7
Any--END--Pattern     # print 8
```

Comment: Much nicer than the `perl`-based answer and more understandable than the `sed`-based answer. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Perl to the rescue!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $last_end;
my @buffer;
while (<>) {
    if (/BEGIN/) {

        print @buffer[ 0 .. $last_end ] if defined $last_end;

        @buffer = $_;
        undef $last_end;
        next;
    }
    $last_end = @buffer if @buffer && /END/;
    push @buffer, $_ if @buffer;
}
```

`@buffer` accumulates the lines from BEGIN, `$last_end` points to, well, the last END in the buffer, so you can throw away accumulated lines that don't end in an END.

As a one-liner (but why?):

```
perl -ne 'defined $l && print(@B[0..$l]), (@B, $l) = $_, next if /BEGIN/; $l=@B if @B && /END/; push @B, $_ if @B' file
```

Comment: Hardly a one-liner though ;)

Comment: @simbabque: Updated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This should work with sed

```
sed '$b1;/BEGIN/{:1;x;s/\(BEGIN.*END[^\n]*\).*/\1/;t;x;h};H;d' file
```